# memcached from remote server cannot save data

Tags: php, memcached

I can save data locally, but not remotely.
Is this a file permissions issue?

Here is the usual test code:

```
<?php
$mem = new Memcached();
$mem->addServer("xx.xx.xx.xx", 11211);

$result = $mem->get("blah");

if ($result) {
    echo $result;
} else {
    echo "No matching key found.  I'll add that now!";
    $mem->set("blah", "I am data!  I am held in memcached!") or die("Could not save anything to memcached...");
}
?>
```

On the server and client I installed:

- memcached
- php5-memcached

Do I need to install libmemcached...' as well? or something else?

Comment: I cannot save or retrieve data remotely from memcached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prpblem was with /etc/memcached.conf.

Needed to change the host ip from 127.0.0.1 to my actual network ip.